# terminator problem with running custom command in layout

Tags: terminator, layout

I have problems with running custom commands in terminator layouts, they seem to "hang", maybe I am misunderstanding the concept of custom commands here.

If I run something like `python manage.py runserver` it seems to work fine. But if I run `echo 'Hallo'` as custom command it will be executed, but then it "hangs" and I dont get a new command line and cannot run any more commands in the window. I can't even stop it with strg+c, thats also for the `runserver` command.

I thought, running a custom command will be the same like opening terminator, typing executing the command and then having a normal working command line

Answer (score 5):

ok I just found out :) I just need to add `; bash` after the custom command, should be worth mentioning that in the menu...

Comment: tnx @Jeno, you just save me :D